# QField - Cannot replicate picture gallery on iPhone on a feature

Tags: qgis, qfield

I pretty much tried all day to get QField (V2.8.0 - Insightful Indri) on my iPad Air 2 to show more than one picture for a single feature. It should look something like this (taken from this source https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/pictures/):

[image]

I think I got the tables with their relations right and working correctly. But I don't seem to be able to get QField to actually show the pictures. Instead I get only a list of the path names. For me it looks like this (the date list is showing correctly by the way):

[image]

These are my layers (all GeoPackages):

[image]

These are the Points Layer Properties - Attributes Form:

[image]

These are the Picture Layer Properties - Attributes Form:

[image]

And this is what the Relations look like:

[image]

I would much appreciate if anyone was in a position to help me get the QField gallery view of pictures rather than the path-names-list which I am only currently getting.